# Using libmms and audioqueue

Tags: iphone, mms, audioqueueservices

I've been playing with libmms and iPhone for a bit, and I have managed to connect and read from the mms stream, but after this I'm at a loss of how to send the data from mmsx_read into the AudioQueue, I assume it will have to be using the AudioQueueNewOutput method from [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html)... I've spent quite a bit of time searching but I can't find any examples...

I also took a look at the code for WunderRadio but only the header files are in the released code.

I'm also not very familiar with objc or c, I've dabbled in both but wouldn't consider myself an expert, so any pointers/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same think for radio streaming application. I am able to get wma file using libmms library. And using that with ffmpeg I can convert in in the mp3 format..

Comment: Can you help me with the same. I am a student and need to submit an App that can play WMA stream for my project. I have the libmms library from TuneIn Radio project. I don't know hot to go on from here.

Comment: Hi @AppAspect, I'm working on a project that using libmms to read WMA stream and convert it to mp3. What you've done is what I'm looking for. Can you please give some guide or sample code about this? Very appreciated.

Comment: I have done using libmms and ffmpeg but there were some memory leaks so not able to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The SpeakHere example app, with source code on developer.apple.com, contains a nice example of using Audio Queues for playing and recording using audio buffers.

If you know how to convert data types, if necessary, and how to copy PCM samples from a stream to buffer arrays, then you should be good to go.

Objective C is a proper superset of C, so learning basic C idioms, such as its data types and how to use arrays of short ints, is always useful.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that, I've been reading a few C books to get up to date on it...